# Cannot return String from function

Tags: ios, swift, string, function

I've tried to return `String` from my function, but I get error "Use of unresolved identifier nameOfFlower". Here's my function:

```
func detectFlower(image: CIImage) -> String {
        guard let model = try? VNCoreMLModel(for: FlowerModels().model) else {
            fatalError("Cannot import a model.")
        }

        let request = VNCoreMLRequest(model: model) { (request, error) in

            let classification = request.results?.first as? VNClassificationObservation

            var nameOfFlower = String(classification?.identifier ?? "Unexpected type")



        }

        let handler = VNImageRequestHandler(ciImage: image)

        do {
            try handler.perform([request])
        } catch {
            print(error)
        }

        return nameOfFlower
       }
```

What is wrong with code?

Comment: Don't leave us hanging. What was the rest of the error message? Please post *exactly* what you get.

Comment: you need to retur completion block instead of return

Comment: its async code .. so use closure

Comment: @tadman I'm sorry, I already edited code.

Comment: The 'nameOfFlower' is in the wrong scope. You're trying to call and return it when it's already been forgotten.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Returning data from async call in Swift function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25203556/returning-data-from-async-call-in-swift-function)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its async code .. so use closure as completion block

```
func detectFlower(image: CIImage,completion: @escaping (_ getString:String?,_ error:Error?)-> Void)  {
     guard let model = try? VNCoreMLModel(for: FlowerModels().model) else {

         fatalError("Cannot import a model.")
     }

     let request = VNCoreMLRequest(model: model) { (request, error) in

         let classification = request.results?.first as? VNClassificationObservation

         var nameOfFlower = String(classification?.identifier ?? "Unexpected type")

         completion(nameOfFlower,nil)

     }

     let handler = VNImageRequestHandler(ciImage: image)

     do {
         try handler.perform([request])
     } catch {
         print(error)
           completion(nil,error)
     }


    }
```

**How to use**

```
     detectFlower(image: yourImage) { (flowerString, error) in
                // you get optional flower string here
            }
```